# Removing a div or a class affect another div

Tags: html, css

As a beginner this bug seems pretty strange and since i can't put all code here(large) I will be happy to even hear where to begin. 
If more code needed I will provide.

I have this :

```
<div class="labeledInput">
  <label class="font">Tap To Add Your Photo:</label>
  <div class="imagePreview logoPreview" id="logoPreview" style="background-image: url(images/Holder.png);">
    <input type="file" id="logoPreview">
  </div>
</div>
```

If I remove this row (and only this) :

```
<div class="imagePreview logoPreview" id="logoPreview" style="background-image: url(images/logoHolder.png);">
```

or even remove the class `imagePreview` from it, or set it without a class at all:

```
<div class="logoPreview" id="logoPreview" style="background-image: url(images/logoHolder.png);">
```

Then another `button` that is *far away* , turns to be a file upload button when clicked, instead of just a button that scroll (using JS) when clicked.

This is the affected button(not related at all to the code above) :

```
<div class="nextButton">
  <input type="image" src="https://picsum.photos/50/50" onclick='nextButton()'/>
</div>
```

**EDIT :**

I found that in my CSS, if I remove this style - the bug will not happen :

```
.imagePreview img
{
  max-width: 100%;
  pointer-events: none;
}

//***** this one if removed solve the problem but make an ugly button*****
[type="file"] {
  cursor: pointer;
  opacity: 0;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
}
```

Comment: Really hard to say... Are you sure you don't have unclosed tags somewhere?

Comment: Thanks, anything else I can provide? how a css class can affect another html tag functionality ? I counted divs, is there a way to count all other tags ?

Comment: You should make sure all the tags are closed correctly (so you don't have any markup errors), than you could inspect your elements and see how it looks in the DOM inspector, also, what does `nextButton()` do? (And why oh why you use inline JS) Is some `Event.preventDefault()` missing? Have you inspected all the bound listeners to your bugging elements? Again, hard to say, use the Developer Tools. Investigate! You'll eventually find your errors.

Comment: Thanks very much. Will do now. Just out of curiosity , how removing a class name, can affect anything else ? maybe without this css the button is huge and affect another button ?

Comment: Out of the back of my neck... no idea. Do you have all that stuff wrapped inside a `<form>` element..? Now, out of curiosity I'd really like to see a live example of your issue.

Comment: Thanks, I found something, please see the EDIT of my question.\

Comment: See :) Developer console is your best friend! That file button was covering the entire area, transparent but stealing all clicks. Regarding the ugly file button - that's up to you - or your designer. So your main problem was CSS. Nothing else.

Comment: @RokoC.Buljan thanks a lot ! i have no designer, since I am a beginner in css, how should i solve this problem with code? not sure yet what exactly it is, I need to have this image that when clicked you can upload a photo. How to change this code to work without affecting other things ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

add `position` as `relative` to parent class

```
.imagePreview{    
    position: relative;
}
```

Comment: that solved it, why is it relate at all ? how when some other html is not including this class, it affect another one ? how position solve this ?

Comment: it is important to know that if you add position as absolute to any element it is mandatory to add position relative to its parent element due to this the change only applicable absolutely to that element